Is the forced dark mode flag in Chromium-based browsers supported?
Chromium-based browsers support a feature flag about:flags/#enable-force-dark to force a dark theme on sites. Over the years this feature has existed, we've gotten many bug reports of things not working right when this flag is used (example; also see reports under the dark-mode tag).
It's known that bugs caused by browser extensions and user scripts are not supported by SE, but this feature flag is technically a built-in feature of a supported browser rather than an extension. As such, there's always been some confusion as to whether bugs caused by enabling it are supported that seems to come up on many of these bug reports.
As such, it would be nice if there were an official response from SE as to whether this feature flag, when used in supported browsers, is supported.

It's tricky to support it properly because a browser in forced dark mode responds to media queries as if it's using a light theme. You can test that with the examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme Also, the various Chromium-based browsers have idiosyncratic ways of implementing the light-dark inversions.

I don't think it makes much sense to ask whether this is "supported". my understanding (perhaps wrong) is that this is a browser-level-user-configurable override of site styles. If anything, why not ask about prefers-color-scheme?
